# How can I make the bot ban when someone uses "pls rob" and mentions someone after it?

Tags: python, discord.py

```
if message.content.lower() == 'pls rob':
  await message.delete()
  await message.author.send('Oof you got banned.')
  await message.author.ban(reason="Robbing")
```

Is my current code, I'm not exactly sure how to make it work when someone else mentions someone outside of "pls rob"/"pls rob @Someone"

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
if message.content.lower().startswith('pls rob'): <--
    await message.delete()
    await message.author.send('Oof you got banned.')
    await message.author.ban(reason="Robbing")
```